# Is it a good practices if I give helpful information about operating the search box to user?

Tags: forms, ux-field, formatting, information

On my data tables view, I have a search box that search information from database and shows it on the data tables. There are any need to use button with the search box? I use key up event handler ( press enter key to submit form ) so that when user press enter search box data will be submitted & searching result will be shown in the table.

Now, I need to know without submit button can I use search box in the data tables view? Can I tell helpful information about operating the search box?

Like as this screenshot...

[image]

Comment: UI is like a joke. If you have to explain it, it isn't very good.

Comment: @dennislees nice ans :D

Comment: thanks : ) but it's not my line. I heard it in a presentation at a conference, and I'm pretty sure that  person didn't come up with it either ;  )

Comment: @dennislees yeah. But, It's sound like cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is NOT good practise. Good UI practise would be when you don't have to explain what the user has to do. Especially with something simple as a search box, it should be instantly clear.

To achieve this I would:

- Move the text "Search:" within the box. This way people will understand that that's the place to search. And it also tells what the input is for.
- Add a magnifier icon to clarify there is no submit button, whatsoever. For the best user experience I would make the magnifier clickable as a submit button.

[image: Search]

Answer (score 0):

Search boxes are well understood pattern, and often users will look for something to click.

Don't give them an explanation instead, this will just make them slightly more irritated by your interface.

Also, some users will type, then look for the button, at which point your message is gone.

https://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/magnifying-glass-icon/

Answer (score 0):

Users generally understand the functionality of a search box, so "type and press enter" isn't necessary here.  If you really feel it needs explaining because users aren't pressing "enter", then consider adding an "enter" button.

However, It is useful to add some indication in the search field as to **what** the user can search for, as facebook does:

[image: "search for people, places and things"]

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the necessity of trying it out, test it out. If it yields desired results, why not implement it. Also the usage of a magnifying glass tool or both (as in Twitter) might be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends who your users are and what other interfaces they are used to.
I assume most people would hit enter, especially if you will add the little magnifying glass icon. [but UX is not a field where you use assumptions in order to achieve anything]
I recommend:

1. finding a reference that acts the same way (if you can't find one, I suggest rethinking if you really want to use this method because that means it's not a conventional search area, and people are not used to it).
2. user test the prototype or even the beta, just ask users to find something and watch how they attempt to do it, and where do they fail.